# Issue with Start, Stop JAR file with batch Script

Tags: java, spring, batch-file, jar

I am trying to start and stop jar file using batch script.
The scripts are,

start.bat:

```
@ECHO OFF
call run.bat start
```

stop.bat:

```
@ECHO OFF
call run.bat stop
```

run.bat:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF "%1"=="start" (
    ECHO start your app
    start "app" java  -jar app.jar
) ELSE IF "%1"=="stop" (
    ECHO stop app
    TSKILL "WINDOWTITLE eq app"
) ELSE (
    ECHO please, use "run.bat start" or "run.bat stop"
)
pause
```

I am able to start run the jar. But I am not able to stop the app. Seems the TSKILL is only available admin command prompt only.

**Requirement:**

1. I want to run the jar file in background terminal to hide the java compiler details. It should only show App is running.
2. TSKILL by batch file. (Seems TSKILL only works in admin command prompt, batch file opens normal terminal). - error is coming "TSKILL not found command". Not Sure.

Any Support?

Comment: try `START /B "app" java  -jar app.jar > somefile.txt`

Comment: thank you. It solves the first requirement. Any support on stop the JAR file by batch script?

Comment: Why are you using `TSKill`? Are you trying to end a process running in a session on a Remote Desktop Host? Does that process belong to you? Or are you running this as Administrator? or elevated?

Comment: As asked by Compo, are your trying to kill task on Remote Desktop? In your local it is `taskkill` not `tskill`. Maybe this one `taskkill /u username /p password /s system-ip "WINDOWTITLE eq app"`

Comment: Same local machine only. TASKKILL is not working for me in admin command prompt as well normal cmd. TSKILL only working for me, that too in admin command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know If I am late or what but surely someone would benefit. I got it working this way:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF "%1"=="start" (
 ECHO start your app
 start "app" java  -jar MyJar.jar) 
ELSE IF "%1"=="stop" (
 ECHO stop app
 TASKKILL /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq app") 
ELSE (ECHO please, use "test.bat start" or "test.bat stop")
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

If your java code does not have any GUI interface, and even the command prompt window it might be running in shall be hidden, you could replace java with javaw and see how that goes.
As for the stopping of the process you would not even have a window title to find it, so that would not work.

But if it is important for the application to run in the background, why don't you try to register it as a Windows Service? Then there is a nice command like "net start ..." and "net stop ..." to control the service. All you need to check is either [Tanuki Service Wrapper](https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp) or [Apache Commons-Daemon](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/).